# Problems with executing an AsyncTask within a static function

Tags: android, function, static, android-asynctask

I'm trying to execute a doInBackground AsycTask from a static function, but when I try to enter in the parms for Void, I get a Java error, saying 'Void' is not applicable for the Task
'String, Void, Boolean'

Anyway, here's my code:

```
public class RequestHandler extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Boolean> {

    //atributes for Async
    private static Context context;
    private RequestHandler origin;

 // Constructor
    public RequestHandler(Context c) {

        origin = this;
        context = c;

    }

   public static boolean doLogin(String username, String password) {
       String URL = "http://127.0.0.1:1337";
new RequestHandler(context).execute(URL, Void, false); // what do I put here?  
   }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(URL... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        URL url = null;
        try {
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
           try {
             InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             readStream(in);
           } finally {

           }
        return false;

           }
            private String readStream(InputStream is) {
                try {
                  ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                  int i = is.read();
                  while(i != -1) {
                    bo.write(i);
                    i = is.read();
                  }
                  return bo.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  return "";
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the 'doLogin method outside the AsyncTask class
2. `new RequestHandler(context).execute(URL);`
3. `protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {`....}

Comment: What!? Putting DoLogin OUTSIDE the class? !??

Comment: Yes, why did you link me to a tutorial of Async? I know where all the variables are passed to.

Comment: I'm just saying, I don't need to fobbed with a tutorial, I just need a basic answer as I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Where you call your RequestHandler in the doLogin method, your are trying to use Void as an object but it is a type, try changing that line to :

```
new RequestHandler(context).execute(URL, null, false);
```

and get your AsyncTask to return null instead.